# Matlab - change axis multiplier

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Could you tell me how can I change an axis "multiplier"? I mean a value I circled in the picture, let's say I would like to have x10^3 instead of x10^4.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Matlab Central **tick2text: create easy-to-customize tick labels**

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16003-tick2text-create-easy-to-customize-tick-labels

along with the `sprintf` formatting.

Comment: It seems the fastest way from all of the answers. Here is the code if somebody would has a problem `tick2text(gca,'yformat', @(x) sprintf('%2u', x/10^9)` Thx @Macduff.

Answer (score 5):

As of R2015b it is part of the Numeric Ruler Properties:

```
ax = get(gca);
ax.YAxis.Exponent = -3;
```

Answer (score 3):

I have little bit tricky solution:

1. Set `YTickMode` to `manual`.
2. Set your own `YTickLabel`.
3. Place the text on top with your desired multiplier.

here is:

```
set(gca, 'YTickMode', 'manual');
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca,'YTick') / 1000);
text(0, 1.02 * get(gca,'YLim')(2), 'x 10^3');
```

Play with the multiplier `1.02` in the third line to place your text to the good place.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I don't want to change axis limits, but values on the axis. In my example, I need to have values 0,10,20,...,100 with x10^3 multiplier instead of 0,1,2,...,10 with x10^4 multiplier on my y-axis

Comment: Sorry, I thoght `num2str` of an array will create new array with strings, not the string line. I also noticed, that num2str was redundant. Try now.

Comment: Ok, it works like a charm now with an one exception. I had to change `text(0, 1.02 * get(gca,'YLim')(2), 'x 10^3');` to `tmp = get(gca,'YLim'); text(0, 1.02 * tmp(2), 'x 10^3');`. Perhaps my version doesn't accept your type of index expression. Anyway, that's an acceptable answer as well. Thank you!

Comment: I would use `'{\times}10^3'` for `text`.

Answer (score 1):

Scale your data by 0.1, which gives you the multiplier you want.

Then override the tick labels so that tick 1.0 is labelled 10, etc.

Comment: But overriding the tick labels removes the multiplier, doesn't it?

Comment: @Luis: I saw some plots where it didn't, but they might have done something exotic.